# Visual Studio Code Python: Quick open a file in $VIRTUAL_ENV

Tags: python, navigation, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to setup a VS Code to allow Quick Open (`Cmd+P` / `Ctrl+P`) a source file in current virtual env (outside my project folder)

E.g. open a Django (or any other 3rd party) source file

Answer (score 1):

Since Visual Studio Code now supports multiple root workspaces, you could add your virtual environment to it. Then Quick Open will work.